# Multiple Sinon stubs against global window not working as expected

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner, sinon

I'm using Karma with Mocha, Chai and Sinon to test code in a project using [this boilerplate](https://github.com/ufocoder/redux-universal-boilerplate). The Subject Under Test uses the [Speech Synthesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis) API.

I start by establishing `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices` in a `beforeEach` method

```
beforeEach(() => {
    global.window.speechSynthesis = {
        getVoices: () => (null),
    };
});
```

Then I have two test cases, in each one, I want to test what happens when a different set of voices is returned. To accomplish this I'm using [Sinon stubs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v3.3.0/stubs/)

**First test case**

```
it('supports speech and locale', () => {
    const getVoicesStub = sinon.stub(
        global.window.speechSynthesis,
        'getVoices');

    getVoicesStub.callsFake(() => (
        [{lang: 'en_US'}]
    ));
```

**Second test case**

```
it('will choose best matching locale', () => {
    const getVoicesStub = sinon.stub(
        global.window.speechSynthesis,
        'getVoices');

    getVoicesStub.callsFake(() => (
        [{lang: 'es_MX'}, {lang: 'es_US'}]
    ));
```

The problem is, when the SUT calls `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices` during the second test case, it's getting the results from the first stub. It's as if the second stub is doing nothing...

If I comment out the first test case, the second test case succeeds, but if I leave them both in, the second one fails because the wrong set of voices are being returned.

Any idea how to get the second stub to work as expected?

Comment: Try to create the stub only once in `before`

Comment: @Troopers How will I change the data between test cases if I move the stub into `beforeEach`?

Comment: Your stub is the same between the 2 tests, you can change only callsFake in each test

Comment: How will I do this without a global property? I will need some way to reference the stub from the test cases, yet when I define a global property I get this error `Strict mode forbids implicit creation of global property 'getVoicesStub'`

Comment: Declare your stub in local in your tests suite not in global

Comment: I tried that, declaring `getVoicesStub` directly beneath the `describe` before `beforeEach`, but I get the same error.

Comment: NM - it was a typo, but even then I still am back to the original problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your stub is not destroyed between tests. You need to restore the default function after a test and create your stub only once in `before`

```
describe("Test suite", () => {

    let getVoicesStub;

    before(() => {
        // executes before suite starts
        global.window.speechSynthesis = {
            getVoices: () => (null),
        };

        getVoicesStub = sinon.stub(global.window.speechSynthesis, 'getVoices');
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        // executes after each test
        getVoicesStub.restore();
    });

    it('supports speech and locale', () => {
        getVoicesStub.callsFake(() => ([{lang: 'en_US'}]));
    });

    it('will choose best matching locale', () => {
        getVoicesStub.callsFake(() => ([{lang: 'es_MX'}, {lang: 'es_US'}]));
    });
});
```

Comment: I added the `afterEach`, but the results are the same. The stub creation is now only in `beforeEach` as you have it here.

Comment: Tried it, same result.

Comment: So it looks like in the second test case, after I call `getVoicesStub.callsFake()`, it's still returning `null`. I've also tried `global.window.speechSynthesis.getVoices.restore()` with the same result. Agree with you though, your solution looks like it *should* work. I'll keep experimenting.

Comment: Got it working!! Will put the details in a separate answer just so it's out there.

Answer (score 0):

First off, big-ups to @Troopers. Just adding this answer to share the final solution and details I noticed along the way.

---

The real trick was adding a test-suite-level variable `let getVoicesStub`, then defining an `afterEach` method to `restore` the original function

```
afterEach(() => {
    getVoicesStub.restore();
});
```

A subtle caveat to @Troopers suggestion about defining the stub in a `before` method -

If the stub is defined outside of the test cases, I have to use a `beforeEach`, if the stub is defined within the test cases, I have to use a `before` method.

In both cases, the `afterEach` is critical! I've settled on the `beforeEach` solution as the stub is only defined in one place so there's slightly less code.

```
describe('Browser Speech', () => {
    let getVoicesStub;

    beforeEach(() => {
        global.window.speechSynthesis = {
            getVoices: () => (null),
        };

        getVoicesStub = sinon.stub(
            global.window.speechSynthesis,
            'getVoices');
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        getVoicesStub.restore();
    });

    it('supports speech and locale', () => {
        getVoicesStub.callsFake(() => (
            [{lang: 'en_US'}]
        ));

        // test case code ..
    });

    it('will choose best matching locale', () => {
        getVoicesStub.callsFake(() => (
            [{lang: 'es_MX'}, {lang: 'es_US'}]
        ));


        // test case code ..
    });
});
```